# How can authenticate in dataflow + Apache beam using Java or Kotlin if I have the content of the service account in the variable?

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

I tried this code but It doesn't work. However, the service account is correct.

```
val dataflowOptions = PipelineOptionsFactory.create().`as`(MyOptions::class.java)
       dataflowOptions.jobName = "tesjob1"
       dataflowOptions.project = getGcpProjectId()
       dataflowOptions.region = getGcpRegion()
       dataflowOptions.subnetwork = getGcpSubNetwork()
       dataflowOptions.usePublicIps =false
       dataflowOptions.runner = DataflowRunner::class.java

val serviceAccountJson= ""

val credentials: Credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(ByteArrayInputStream(serviceAccountJson.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)))
dataflowOptions.gcpCredential = credentials

dataflowOptions.setGcpTempLocation("gs://deib_bucket/temp")
return Pipeline.create(dataflowOptions)
```

[image]

Could you give me any suggestions to resolve the issue?

Comment: You can also set the current SA token key differently, if you are interested. it's for local execution ?

Comment: If you are on Dataflow, you don't need a service account key file. Why do you use it here? It's an anti pattern!

Comment: By default, the default SA for Compute Engine is used. For local purpose and testing, sometimes others SA could be used (`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` + program argument : `service_account`)

Comment: What can be the best approach in your opinion? I need it, because it is a microservices and it will receive some requests to launch the pipelines.

Comment: You are in prod condition ?

Comment: Yes, I need the approach that I commented. Also If I need to run some tests how can define the service account if I need to change the service account  taking into account the environment automatically? Our idea is to define the content of the service account in the variable the entorno.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue, I couldn't use the service account because I need to pass the scope, for that I changed the code and now it worked properly.

```
 val gcpSCOPES: List<String> = listOf(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub"
    )

        val options: DataflowPipelineOptions = PipelineOptionsFactory.create().`as`(DataflowPipelineOptions::class.java)
        options.jobName = "jobExample"
        options.project = getGcpProjectId()
        options.region = getGcpRegion()
        options.subnetwork = getGcpSubNetwork()
        options.usePublicIps =false
        options.runner = DataflowRunner::class.java
        options.gcpCredential = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(ByteArrayInputStream(DeibDataSyncEnv.getGcpCredentials().toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)))
            .createScoped(gcpSCOPES)
        options.serviceAccount = getGcpServiceAccountEmail()

options.setGcpTempLocation(DeibDataSyncEnv.getGcpTempLocation())
        return Pipeline.create(dataflowOptions)
```

Comment: In my answer I proposed you explanations for Dataflow and authentication with SA and also some best practices with Flex Templates. I think it’s not a good practice to use token key because it’s not secure. Please may you upvote my answer to help the community to go in the right direction with this kind of issue ?

Answer (score 1):

To help you and give more explanations on `Dataflow` job authentication and the use of Service Account :

If you launch your `Dataflow` job from your local machine, your have to export the  `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var, unfortunately there is no choice in this case.

However if you launch your job via a DAG orchestrator like `Airflow` and Cloud Composer no need to pass a SA key file. The authentication is handled with `Airflow` and the SA used by `Cloud Composer`.

You can also explore other solutions with `Cloud Shell` or `Cloud Build` to launch your job, but I think it's better for the CI CD part to deploy the job and delegate the responsability of job execution to a pipeline orchestration tool like `Airflow`.

In production environment, you can also use `Dataflow Flex Template` to standardize the deployment of your `Dataflow` jobs based on a `bucket` and a `Docker` image.

In this case, if you use a tool like `Cloud Build`, no need to pass a Service Account key file.

You can check this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/ci-cd-for-dataflow-java-with-flex-templates-and-cloud-build-e3c584b8e564) I written, that shows a complete example of CI CD pipeline with `Dataflow Flex Template`.

In prod and to have the best standardisation for your jobs, I think `Flex template` should be the best solution.

An example of command to deploy a job with `Flex Template` :

```bash
gcloud dataflow flex-template build "$METADATA_TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH" \
  --image-gcr-path "$LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG" \
  --sdk-language "$SDK_LANGUAGE" \
  --flex-template-base-image "$FLEX_TEMPLATE_BASE_IMAGE" \
  --metadata-file "$METADATA_FILE" \
  --jar "$JAR" \
  --env FLEX_TEMPLATE_JAVA_MAIN_CLASS="$FLEX_TEMPLATE_JAVA_MAIN_CLASS"
```

An example of command to launch the job with the `serviceAccount` program argument :

```bash
gcloud dataflow flex-template run "$JOB_NAME-$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)" \
  --template-file-gcs-location "$METADATA_TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH" \
  --project="$PROJECT_ID" \
  --region="$LOCATION" \
  --temp-location="$TEMP_LOCATION" \
  --staging-location="$STAGING_LOCATION" \
  --parameters serviceAccount="$SA_EMAIL" \
  --parameters inputJsonFile="$INPUT_FILE" \
  --parameters inputFileSlogans="$SIDE_INPUT_FILE" \
  --parameters teamLeagueDataset="$TEAM_LEAGUE_DATASET" \
  --parameters teamStatsTable="$TEAM_STATS_TABLE" \
  --parameters jobType="$JOB_TYPE" \
  --parameters failureOutputDataset="$FAILURE_OUTPUT_DATASET" \
  --parameters failureOutputTable="$FAILURE_OUTPUT_TABLE" \
  --parameters failureFeatureName="$FAILURE_FEATURE_NAME"
```